# How to read the XSD datetime format in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, datetime, xsd, format

Is there a function, class, or extension in PHP that can handle the [XSD datetime format](http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/schema_dtypes_date.asp)?
It's a standard XML date & time format, that looks like this:

```
<date>2008-02-28T07:56:35.263</date>
```

I know I can read it with a regular expression, if no solution is given, I'll default to that.

Thanks!

PS: Solved, look at the answers.

Comment: A word of caution though: if the date is in the UTC (terminated with Z), the function will convert it to the local timezone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) should be able to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, it was as simple as

```
strtotime( $xsd_formatted_date )
```

I leave the question in case it's useful to others, if not, just delete it.